# Calculating a density=1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had an excercise regarding a family of densities. My question is: Is this really a family of densities? I calculated the integral over $R^2$ and think that it is only a density when a=1, but I might be wrong. Let $$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}e^{-a|x|-a^{-1}|y|}$$ so I calculated the integral over $R^{2}$ and determined that is is one iff a=1, can anyone defy? $a\in(0,\infty)$

Comment: If density in this context means probability density, then the integral must be $1$.

Comment: I know, but according to my calculation it is one only if a=1, but should be for all a in $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Ech, I think you may be right, but they should have written it... i lost time and points because of that on my exam. Precisely, it is written let the probability measure $\mu_a$ be on $R^{2}$ with the density I have written.

Comment: "so I calculated the integral over R2 and determined that is is one iff a=1" We cannot know where you erred since you do not show what you did...

Comment: I already know my mistake thanks, I was so tired that I added $\frac{a}{2}+\frac{2}{a}$ instead of multiplying them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{R^2} g(x,y)dxdy=(\frac{1}{2}\int_R e^{-a^{-1}|y|}dy)(\frac{1}{2}\int_R e^{-a|x|}dx)={(a)(\frac{1}{a})=1}$,

for all $a\gt 0$.